# TypeScript Allow only child items of parent object in parameter

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have the following `interfaces`. I would like to declare `objects` from those `interfaces` (like `Actor`/`Film`) and pass them into a class (`From`). The class, `From`, has a method, `Select`, where I only want them to take children of the passed object (`Actor`). Am I going about this incorrectly? Is there a better way? This isn't working and I'm not quite how to go about it.

```
interface ColumnString {
    maxLength: number
}

type ColumnType = ColumnString | typeof Number | typeof Date

interface Column {
    toString: () => String 
    column: ColumnType
}

interface Table {
    toString: () => string
    columns: { [columnName: string]: Column }
}

const Actor: Table = {
    toString: () => "Actor",
    columns: {
        FirstName: {
            toString: () => "FirstName", column: { maxLength: 50 }
        },
        LastName: {
            toString: () => "LastName", column: { maxLength: 50 }
        },
        BirthDate: {
            toString: () => "BirthDate", column: Date
        }
    }
}

const Film: Table = {
    toString: () => "Film",
    columns: {
        FilmTitle: {
            toString: () => "FilmTitle", column: { maxLength: 100 }
        },
        Rating: {
            toString: () => "Rating", column: { maxLength: 5 }
        }
    }
}

// This doesn't work
type TableColumn<T extends Table> = { [P in keyof T["columns"]]: Column } 

class From1<T extends Table> {
    private table: T
    private columns: TableColumn<T>

    constructor(table: T) {
        this.table = table
    }

    public Print() {
        console.log("Table:", this.table.toString())
        Object.keys(this.columns).forEach((column, idx) => {
            console.log("Column", idx+":", column.toString())
        })
    }

    // This doesn't work.
    public Select(...columns: TableColumn<T>[]) {
        this.columns = columns
        return this
    }

}

function From<T extends Table>(table: T) {
    return new From1(table)
}

const A = Actor.columns
const F = Film.columns

From(Actor)
    // Should fail when I pass in F.FilmTitle but be OK with
    // any Actor Column
    .Select(A.FirstName, F.FilmTitle)
    .Print()
```

I tried a bunch of things but am just not sure how to go about it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flow the name of the column/table as a string literal type. You can then use the fact that different string literal types are incompatible to ensure that you can't pass to `Select` columns of a different table.

I had to change the structure of the classes a bit, to have a `name` property, also there is some extra initialization that has to be done on the table and the columns so I had to add some extra function, but the result is actually quite usable.

**Usage**

```
const Actor = table("Actor", {
    FirstName: { maxLength: 50 },
    LastName: { maxLength: 50 },
    BirthDate: Date
});

const Film = table("Actor", {
    FilmTitle: { maxLength: 50 },
    Rating:{ maxLength: 50 },
});

const A = Actor.columns
const F = Film.columns

From(Actor)
    // A.FirstName is ok, F.FilmTitle fails
    .Select(A.FirstName, F.FilmTitle)
    .Print()
```

**Implementation**

```
type ColumnType = { maxLength: number } | (new () => Date); //For testing 

interface Column<TName = string, TOwnerName = string> {
    name: TName;
    tableName : TOwnerName;
    column: ColumnType;
    toString(): string;

}

interface Table<TName, TColumns extends { [name: string]: Column }> {
    name: TName;
    toString(): string;
    columns: TColumns
}

function table<TTableName extends string, TColumns extends { [name: string]: ColumnType }>(tableName: TTableName, columnTypes: TColumns) :  Table<TTableName, { [P in keyof TColumns] : Column<P, TTableName>}> {
    let columns :{ [P in keyof TColumns] : Column<P, TTableName>} = {} as any;
    for(let key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(columnTypes)) {
        columns[key] = {
            name: key, 
            toString : () => key,
            column: columnTypes[key],
            tableName: tableName
        }
    }

    return {
        name: tableName,
        toString: () => tableName,
        columns
    };
}

class From1<TTableName extends string, TColumns  extends { [name: string] : Column }> {
    private table: Table<TTableName, TColumns>
    private columns: Column<keyof TColumns, TTableName>[]

    constructor(table: Table<TTableName, TColumns>) {
        this.table = table
    }

    public Print() {
        console.log("Table:", this.table.toString())
        this.columns.forEach((column, idx) => {
            console.log("Column", idx + ":", column.toString())
        })
    }
    public Select<TColumnName extends keyof TColumns>(...columns: Column<TColumnName, TTableName>[]) {
        this.columns = columns
        return this
    }

}

function From<TTableName extends string, TColumns  extends { [name: string] : Column<string> }>(table: Table<TTableName, TColumns>) {
    return new From1(table)
}
```